# create txtfile from website and save to server

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, file-transfer, web-to-winforms

I have attempted to find a way to download a file (from a PC running a Winform written in VB) from a web directory but could not get this done due to the date stamp that gets generated once the file is saved (filename must be precise). So now I'm trying the reverse (saving the file to the PC directly from the creation of the file).

Does anyone have any suggestions on methods to use (please no FTP due to proxy restrictions, same goes for client/server TCP/UDP). this will always be a .txt file.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you see the file contents in a browser via a URL?

Comment: I should be able to but for some reason can see them.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean you cannot see them. If so then you would need to sort that out first. Then you could use HttpWebRequest to GET the file contents and write it out to a file.

Comment: I will sort it out in the morning. how is the HttpWebRequest (GET) method implemented?

Comment: I can see the files now (sorry about the Typo). With the HttpWebRequest, would I be able to download the file without knowing what the full file name is? This would work if I new how to determine the full file name (the file name has a custom date/timestamp added to it)

Comment: You can use the HttpWebRequest to get the page that lists the file(s). In the answer below just GET the HTML for the page textfiles.com/100 and parse it for the file name(s)

Comment: how can I include credentials for the below? I currently get a 403 error "Forbidden"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can see the file contents by navigating to the URL, you can use an HttpWebRequest and a StreamReader / StreamWriter to save the data.

I'm downloading an example from http://textfiles.com/100/914bbs.txt

```
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest

    request = WebRequest.Create("http://textfiles.com/100/914bbs.txt")

    request.Method = "GET"

    Dim response = request.GetResponse

    Using reader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream)

        Using writer As New StreamWriter("C:\myfilename.txt")
            writer.Write(reader.ReadToEnd)
        End Using

    End Using
```

Comment: Depending on how your site is set up, you may want to use Server.MapPath to drop the file to a location under IIS control. Windows may block you from writing outside the web directory (which will throw an error), especially when you're running as an anonymous user.

Comment: Should the Server.MapPath be written in the website?

Comment: Admittedly, I'm not very familiar with Server.MapPath. The above assumes if you can navigate to the URL of the file and it shows you the contents of the file (like with the link from textfiles.com).